# How to detect moving object on a moving conveyor using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, motion-detection

I'm building a grading system for crabs. In this system, the animals (crabs) are placed in a moving conveyor and I need to identify dead or alive animals by detecting its motion based on images captured by a camera on this conveyor. 
The color of conveyor belt is black.

As the conveyor is always moving, so I can't apply methods using stationary camera like [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/). Does anyone have a suggestion about motion detection of the animals in this case using opencv? I can use more than one camera if it's necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most obvious answer is:
1) adjust the pictures of the conveyor in the different periods of time so that they become of the same area.
2) watch which ones of the crabs have different poses (like, "substract the images") - different regions (pixels) mean that there happened a motion.

If using a tracking - well, you should train your classifier to watch the crabs, and than compare the regions of crabs in a same way. But i think it's too complicated for your particular issue.

Comment: Thanks Slesher for the great idea. With your suggestion, I understood that we need to track the object first and then compare the different regions (pixels) of that object to detect motion. And to track the object only in slightly different backgrounds, we need to train a classifer. Could you please give me some more details about tools and steps to test this solution? Or any similar case so I can learn. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Slesher, I found a video about tracking object in video. https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/. I will test this one to see what I can achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is an interesting question. While weighing different solutions to the problem, I learned that crabs are ectothermal animals, i.e. they can not control their body temperatures but rather their body temperatures are equal to the temperatures of the environment they are in. So, using a remote thermometer is out of question. (But I learned something new, thank you for that :] )

A different, but a little bit cruel method would be, to give take a shot of a crab on the the belt, then give it a nudge of electric pulse (very very small voltage, enough for it to make it react only, similar to us when we get a static discharge) and take another shot of the crab immediately. Compare two images to see if there is a difference in crab's movements. If so, it should be alive, if not, RIP crab.

There are downsides of this solution too:

1. I really do not like the idea of giving electric shocks to crabs,
   even if it is low voltage. Sounds very cruel to me. I am not sure,
   if it is legally doable where you live in either.
2. This requires adding another step to process.
3. I absolutely have no idea what would be a amount of voltage to be
   used in such a system. Would it pose any danger for the employees
   around the conveyor belt?

[I hope I am not get stoned for suggesting giving electric shocks to crabs here]

Comment: Thanks Alp for your suggestion. Actually, I used to think about using infrared sensor to detect the vitality condition of this animal. But, obviously, it can't work for cold blood species (both crab and lobster). Therefore, I'm thinking about using image processing solution for motion detection. I like your idea about using electric pulse to make the animal react. But, the problem here is that, the conveyor is moving, so the backgrounds are quite different between images. So, I don't know which method in opencv is suitable for motion detction of object in this case.